# How to execute run.py script in venv in flask for windows?

Tags: python, flask

I am following the [miguel grinberg tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for flask.

When it comes to running the script from python interpreter in virtualenv, I am stuck. First I will like to know what he means by this step? How to run it?

To my understanding: I installed flask inside my microblog folder, with the `virtualenv flask` command that is mentioned. The following is my file structure: `C:\Users\myuser\microblog\flask` and I have stored the `run.py` file in the folder Scripts which is in `flask` folder.

I tried to run the `flask\Scripts\python run.py` command from the `python.exe` file in scripts, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do not write any of your files inside the virtual environment. Put the `run.py` file in `C:\Users\myuser\microblog\`. Then `cd` to this directory and run the application with:

```
flask\Scripts\python run.py
```

Comment: tried doing that , getting an error in my cmd: fatal error unable to load file system codec. no module named encodings. trying to figure out what this is.

Comment: Should i be making any changes in my environment variables incase i moved my python to another location. current location of python folder is: C:\Users\myuser\Python\Python35-32

Comment: I would uninstall and reinstall Python in the right folder to make sure it is installed correctly.

Comment: yup. installed python 3.4 again and my problem was solved. thank you. :)